# Changing images on hovering

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the image on hovering. I wrote the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
         <title>Selecting Images
         </title>
     </head>
     <body>
            <h1> Image Roll over </h1>

            <a href="#">
                 <img src="first.gif" width="100px" height="50px" name="button"/>
            </a>
            <a href="#"
onmouseover="document.images.button.src='second.gif'"
onmouseout="document.images.button.src='first.jpg' " >
     </body>
</html>
```

But I am unable to load the image on the page.After checking console, I got the following output:
GET file:///C:/Users/Md%203Shahjahan/Documents/mystuff/first.gif net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Which URL are you using to access the site?

Comment: try copying some `first.jpg` and `second.gif` images to the folder `C:/Users/Md 3Shahjahan/Documents/mystuff`

Comment: I am not accessing any site. I have made it to point '#' ( no where ).

Comment: Maybe you meant first.jpg instead of first.gif in the html?

Comment: @KingKing I did the same...

Comment: @EnKrypt No I was thinking that there is problem with extension . But it is not working

Comment: Are you sure the files are placed properly in the working directory?

Comment: I'm not talking about the anchor URL, but the browser URL you are entering to view your page. Something like `http://localhost/mysite`. What happen if you try to access the file like this: `http://localhost/mysite/first.jpg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` tag obviously missed a closing tag, you need to add some text for it as well, like this:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.images.button.src='second.gif'"
            onmouseout="document.images.button.src='first.gif'">Hover me</a>
```

**NOTE**: You should not use inline script. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SnSLk/2/)

Looks like you may want to handle the hovering on the image itself, so it should be like this:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.images.button.src='second.gif'"
            onmouseout="document.images.button.src='first.gif'">
  <img src="first.gif" width="100px" height="50px" name="button"/>
</a>
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SnSLk/3/).

Comment: @jahan there should not be that error if you copied the files to the folder it reported (that is `C:/Users/Md 3Shahjahan/Documents/mystuff`), of course it appears to me that your HTML file already locates in that folder.

Comment: yes Sir u r right. But how to fix it. if i will go through your method will it fix the problem..

Comment: @jahan my answer just pointed out what's wrong in your code, about your files, looks like there is not any file named `first.gif` in the folder, so the first step is to **copy some displayable file named first.gif` to that folder**, then test your code. If it still reports the same error, I can't think of any reason for why. **Unless** you don't do exactly what need to do (which I think the previous comment of mine has already shown).

Answer (score 2):

i would use css to handle these instead of javascript it's cleaner and it will works in all browsers [Fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/SnSLk/4/)

html

```
<h1> Image Roll over </h1>
<a href="#"> </a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x50');
}

a:hover{
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/100/50')
}
```

Comment: beat me to it... css is the best way to handle your objective.